# How does one perform operations only when certain conditions are met for individual values when inputting a numpy array into a function?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm plotting a function over a range of values, so naturally I fed a numpy.arange() into the function to get the dependent values for the plot. However, some of the values are going to NaN or infinity. I know why this is happening, so I went back into the function and included some conditionals. If they were working, these would replace values leading to the NaN outputs only when conditions are met. However, based on the errors I'm getting back, it appears the operations are being performed on every entry in the inputs, rather than only when those conditions are met.

My code is as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

k=10
l=50
pForPlot = np.arange(0,1,0.01)

def ProbThingHappens(p,k,l):
    temp1 = (((1-p)**(k-1)*((k-1)*p+1))**l)
    temp2 = (((1-p)**(1-k))/((k-1)*p+1))
    if float(temp2) <= 1.0*10^-300:
        temp2 = 0
    print("Temp1 = " + str(temp1))
    print("Temp2 = " + str(temp2))
    temp = temp1*(temp2**l-1)
    if math.isnan(temp):
        temp = 1
    print("Temp = " + str(temp))
    return temp

plt.plot(pForPlot,ProbThingHappens(pForPlot,k,l))
plt.axis([0,1,0,1])
plt.xlabel("p")
plt.ylabel("Probability of thing happening")
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,20)
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = (20) 
plt.show()
```

And the error it returns is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-e707ad24af01> in <module>
     20     return temp
     21 
---> 22 plt.plot(pForPlot,ProbAnyOverlapsAtAll(pForPlot,k,l))
     23 plt.axis([0,1,0,0.01])
     24 plt.xlabel("p")

<ipython-input-20-e707ad24af01> in ProbAnyOverlapsAtAll(p, k, l)
     10     temp1 = (((1-p)**(k-1)*((k-1)*p+1))**l)
     11     temp2 = (((1-p)**(1-k))/((k-1)*p+1))
---> 12     if float(temp2) <= 1.0*10^-300:
     13         temp2 = 0
     14     print("Temp1 = " + str(temp1))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How do I specify within the function that I only want to operate on specific values, rather than the whole array of values being produced? I assume that if I know how to get float() to pick out just one value, it should be straightforward to do the same for other conditionals. I'm terribly sorry if this question has been asked before, but I searched for answers using every phrasing I could imagine. I'm afraid in this case I may simply not know know the proper terminology. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like `temp2[temp2 <= 1.0*10^-300] = 0`?

Comment: @iz_ - That worked! Thanks so much. :)